# Runing Wamp Server on windows 7

Tags: php, wampserver

I have installed `wampserver` 3.0.6 on win 7 32 bit. I have also installed `vc_redist.x86`. when I opened `wampserver`, I received following error:

> The procedure entry point ucrtbase.terminate could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll

Please guide me how can I can fix this error?

Comment: have you tried search for solution on internet first ? did you find nothing or you tried and could not solve it? copy the error and paste it on google.

Comment: issue is usually caused by corrupt or outdated Visual C++ Redist where another program has overwritten the libraries. download latest version of VC